# Web api not redirecting to identity server login page

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, identityserver4

I am trying to implement SSO using identity server and Web Api

So far I have created an identity server project and a single Web Api project and configured them according to the [Pluralsight course](https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/asp-dot-net-core-oauth/table-of-contents) I am following. It seems there have been some changes since this course was created so some of what I have had to do doesn't match the tutorial (that could be the cause of my pain point, but I don't think it is).

What I expect to happen is that I hit a controller that requires Authorization and if required I am redirected to the Identity server login page. Currently I get a 401. I looked at the github examples for the [implicit flow here](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Samples/tree/master/Quickstarts/3_ImplicitFlowAuthentication) and it seems I am doing the right thing.

Can someone please help me find what I am missing?

**Identity server**

```
public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddIdentityServer()
                .AddSigningCredential(new X509Certificate2(@"cert.pfx", "password"))
                .AddInMemoryApiResources(Resources.GetApiResources())
                .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(Resources.GetIdentityResources())
                .AddInMemoryClients(Clients.Get())
                .AddTestUsers(Users.Get())
                .AddDeveloperSigningCredential();

        services.AddMvc();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        loggerFactory.AddConsole();

        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();//todo: add if debug

        app.UseIdentityServer();

        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();
    }
}

internal class Resources
{
    public static IEnumerable<IdentityResource> GetIdentityResources()
    {
        return new List<IdentityResource> {
            new IdentityResources.OpenId(),
            new IdentityResources.Profile()
        };
    }

    public static IEnumerable<ApiResource> GetApiResources()
    {
        return new List<ApiResource> {
            new ApiResource("gateway", "Gateway Service")
        };
    }
}

internal class Clients
{
    public static IEnumerable<Client> Get()
    {
        return new List<Client> {
            new Client {
                ClientId = "gatewayClient",
                ClientSecrets = new List<Secret> { new Secret("password".Sha256())},//todo:secure password
                AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.ResourceOwnerPasswordAndClientCredentials,
                AllowedScopes = new List<string> { "gateway" }
            },
            new Client {
                ClientId = "gateway_implicitClient",
                ClientSecrets = new List<Secret> { new Secret("password".Sha256())},//todo:secure password
                AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Implicit,
                AllowedScopes = new List<string> {
                    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
                    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
                    "gateway"
                },
                RedirectUris = new [] { "http://localhost:49942/signin-oidc" },
                PostLogoutRedirectUris = new [] { "http://localhost:49942/signout-callback-oidc" }
            }
        };
    }
}

internal class Users
{
    public static List<TestUser> Get()
    {
        return new List<TestUser> {
            new TestUser {
                SubjectId = "5BE86359-073C-434B-AD2D-A3932222DABE",
                Username = "scott",
                Password = "password"
            }
        };
    }
}
```

**Web api**

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);
        Configuration = builder.Build();

        _container = new Container();
    }

    public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; }
    private Container _container;

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        AddAuthentication(services);
        services.AddMvc();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, IAntiforgery antiforgery)
    {
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseMvc();
    }

    private void AddAuthentication(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        new IdentityServerConfig(services, Configuration);
    }
}

public class IdentityServerConfig
{
    public IdentityServerConfig(IServiceCollection services, IConfigurationRoot configuration)
    {
        services.AddMvcCore()
                .AddAuthorization()
                .AddJsonFormatters();

        services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddIdentityServerAuthentication(options =>
                {
                    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                    options.Authority = "http://localhost:5000";
                    options.ApiName = "gateway_implicit";
                })
                .AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
                {
                    options.SignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                    options.Authority = "http://localhost:5000";
                    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                    options.ClientId = "gateway_implicitClient";
                    options.SaveTokens = true;
                });
    }
}


[Produces("application/json")]
[Route("api/properties")]
public class PropertiesController : AuthController
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("GetProperty/{agentId}/{propertyId}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetProperty(int agentId, Guid propertyId)
    {            
        return Ok(property);
    }
}

using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace MyNameSpace.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [Authorize]
    public class AuthController : ControllerBase
    {

    }
}
```

when I call `http://localhost:49942/api/properties/GetPropertySummaries/1` I can see the below output in the VS

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost:Information: Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:49942/api/properties/GetPropertySummaries/1
>   'dotnet.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\me.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.http.extensions\2.1.1\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Extensions.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
>   'dotnet.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\2.1.6\System.ComponentModel.Annotations.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.DefaultAuthorizationService:Information: Authorization failed.
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker:Information: Authorization failed for the request at filter 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Authorization.AuthorizeFilter'.
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ChallengeResult:Information: Executing ChallengeResult with authentication schemes ().
>   'dotnet.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.identitymodel.tokens\5.2.0\lib\netstandard1.4\Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
>   'dotnet.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\system.identitymodel.tokens.jwt\5.2.0\lib\netstandard1.4\System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
>   'dotnet.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\2.1.6\System.Xml.ReaderWriter.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
>   'dotnet.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.identitymodel.logging\5.2.0\lib\netstandard1.4\Microsoft.IdentityModel.Logging.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
>   'dotnet.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.identitymodel.protocols\5.2.0\lib\netstandard1.4\Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
>   'dotnet.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.identitymodel.protocols.openidconnect\5.2.0\lib\netstandard1.4\Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler:Information: AuthenticationScheme: BearerIdentityServerAuthenticationJwt was challenged.
>   IdentityServer4.AccessTokenValidation.IdentityServerAuthenticationHandler:Information: AuthenticationScheme: Bearer was challenged.
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker:Information: Executed action MyNamespace.PropertiesController.GetPropertySummaries (MyService.Gateway.Service) in 142.4256ms
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost:Information: Request finished in 526.0233ms 401

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For an API (rather than a server-side web application serving up HTML) returning a 401 is the correct behaviour. This would signal to the client (e.g. a javascript client side application) that it needs to get a new token. I.e. it's the client of said API that's responsible for initiating the implicit/hybrid/whatever sign in flow to obtain a suitable bearer token.

If you're adopting the OpenID Connect/OAuth2 way of doing things then you API wouldn't use cookies for authentication at all and would only use bearer token authentication via the AddIdentityServerAuthentication() middleware.